# Comparing the quantum version of the infinite well to classical version

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

In the quantum version of the infinite well, the energy eigenvalues can be precisely determined.

The energy is all in the form of kinetic energy, $E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$, and so, classically, the magnitude of the momentum should be exactly known as well.

But the peaks in $ϕ(p)$ have a finite spread (seen in Fig)
[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: The peaks have finite spread, because you are still in quantum domain, looking at the wave function squared.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362305/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233266/2451 and links therein.