# A couple of apparent inconsistencies on free-particle stationary states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, plane-wave

In order to introduce my question we consider first the free electron, in a box width L, with eigenfunctions and eingenvalues given by  $$\psi_k(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{L}}e^{ikx}$$ and $$E_k=\hbar^2k^2/2m$$ The plane waves are eigenfunctions of the operator $$p=-i\hbar d/dx$$ with eigenvalue $$\hbar k$$ which represents the momentum of the free electron. Obviously the $$\lt p\gt_k=p=\hbar k$$
Now, I have some difficulty with the following

1. The Ehrenfest theorem tells us that:
   $$\lt p\gt=m\frac d{dt}\lt x\gt = m\frac d{dt} (L/2)$$
   but on a stationary state, this derivative is vanishing! So: $$\lt p\gt_k=0\neq\hbar k$$
2. If $$\psi(x)_k$$ is an eigenstate of operator p, then $$\Delta p=0$$ This implies total incertainty on x, i.e. $$\Delta x=\infty$$ ... but we are in a box large L, so I know that the maximum standard deviation for position is $$\Delta =L/2$$

Could someone extricate me these inconsistencies that I can not explain?
I thought that these states are not physically achievable, therefore it doesn't make much sense to ask these questions, but they conflict with my knowledge of quantum mechanics. I found this doubt by studying the band theory and even then I cannot understand how the average speed of an electron in a steady state of Bloch, (n (band index), k (vector wave in fbz)), is not zero.
The only solution I come up with is that they are not really states of the moment, but only of the modulus of the moment and so each of these waves must consider both p and -p ... this would solve both questions.

Thank you for your kind reading and attention!

Comment: Do you mean an electron in a $1D$ box with infinite potential walls? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box#:~:text=In%20quantum%20mechanics%2C%20the%20particle,space%20surrounded%20by%20impenetrable%20barriers.

Comment: @Gert a plane-wave wavefunction is not consistent with an infinite potential well. It is clearly the case of periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: Your wave function is not the wave function of a particle in an infinite square well

Comment: @GiorgioP I'm a bit stumped by 'free particle' and 'in a box of width $L$'... So I thought he had the wrong WF.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233266/how-can-i-solve-this-quantum-mechanical-paradox)

Comment: @Gert it is the usual language in solid state. No potential == free particle, 1D configurations from 0 to L and pbc == box of size L.

Comment: @GiorgioP Thanks. I'm not very familiar with SS QM.

Comment: The link provided by @Jakob is highly relevant. The problem is exactly the same as the problem of the uncertainty relations for angle/angular momentum with momentum eigenstates.

Comment: thanks to all for the interventions. Can you tell me more about mean velocity too?